# Node.js send HTML as response to client

Tags: node.js

Is it possible in Node.js to return HTML (e.g. `<div>Test</div>`) as response to client?

I saw that option in Express on `sendFile()` method().

Is there something similar in Node?

**I found this solution:**

```
var myHtmlData;
fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, data) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    } else {
        myHtmlData = data
    }
  })
  // and after use it 
 response.write(myHtmlData)
```

But I was wondering is it possible to do it with some method similar to `sendFile()` to write html directly like this `<div>Test</div>` without reading it from another file.

Comment: Sure, but you have to do all of the work yourself. If you want to write a server, why not just use Express?

Comment: I want to practice it in Node.js. It is only two lines of code
`http.createServer()` and `server.on('request')` that part about creating server is not complicated.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. It's pretty simple. The following code returns the response as HTML to the client.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
   if(req.url === "/"){
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/html'});
      res.end("<div><p>Test<p></div>");
   }
}).listen(3000);
```

And in case you want to serve an HTML or JSON file as a response, you can execute the following code.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){

    if(req.url === '/I_want_json'){

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'application/json'});

        var obj = {
            firstName: "Jane",
            lastName: "Doe",
        };

        res.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    else if (req.url === '/I_want_html'){
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
        res.end(html);
    }
    else{
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Do not forget to set the **Content-Type** as mentioned since it is a mandatory part for client to distinguish the type of response.

Comment: Thanks, I found similar solution, I wrote it up in question.
I was wondering is it possible to write `html` directly in method without getting it from another file. (I was looking for something similar to JSX in React to return data in that manner)

But this is also helpful.

Comment: Your first answer is what I was looking for. I didn't know that I need to add this `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/html'});` and I was trying without it.

Thanks man!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: In `res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type':'text/html'});` you notify what type of `response` you will send. And that is reason why method `res.end()` or `res.write()` accept `html` type as `response`.
Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to mention the content type as HTML. Then read the HTML file using `fs` module and send its data as a response. Don't forget to end the response using `end()` method.

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  fs.readFile('./views/index.html', (err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    }
  })
});
```